# Slow query responce on different mysql versions, percona, MariaDB

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, percona

LEFT JOIN is supposed to be faster than a NOT IN query. This is what I've read online. But practically, this seems to be opposite. I have the following query here,

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO callrequests (contact, call_status, campaign_id, created_date, active_call) 
SELECT contact, '1', '7', '2013-10-20 13:40:51', '0' FROM contacts c WHERE phonebook_id = '62' and c.`contact` NOT IN (SELECT contact FROM dnc_contacts d WHERE group_id = '3') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE call_status = if( call_status = '2', VALUES(call_status), call_status);
```

which takes around 7 seconds to run. But if I use the same query removing NOT IN, inserting a LEFT JOIN,

```
INSERT IGNORE callrequests (contact, call_status, campaign_id, created_date, active_call) SELECT c.contact, '1', '7', '2013-10-20 13:40:51', '0' FROM contacts c 
LEFT JOIN `dnc_contacts` as B on c.`contact` <> B.`contact` WHERE c.phonebook_id = '62' and B.`group_id` = '3' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE call_status = if( call_status = '2', VALUES(call_status), call_status);
```

show create table callrequests

```
CREATE TABLE `callrequests` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `call_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active_call` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`campaign_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_contact` (`campaign_id`,`contact`),
  KEY `fk_callrequest_campaign1_idx` (`campaign_id`),
  KEY `active_calls` (`active_call`),
  KEY `idx_call_status` (`call_status`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_callrequest_campaign1` FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_id`) REFERENCES `campaigns` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16384 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

show create table contacts

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `phonebook_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '                     ',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`phonebook_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `phonebook_id_contact_INDEX` (`contact`,`status`),
  KEY `contact_INDEX` (`contact`),
  KEY `fk_contact_phonebook1_idx` (`phonebook_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_phonebook1` FOREIGN KEY (`phonebook_id`) REFERENCES `phonebooks` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2484174 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

show create table dnc_contacts

```
CREATE TABLE `dnc_contacts` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`group_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `group_id_satus_contact_INDEX` (`status`),
  KEY `fk_dnc_contact_dnc_group1_idx` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dnc_contact_dnc_group1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `dnc_groups` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32573 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This takes ages to complete. Now the interesting part is that the first query runs very fast (7 seconds) on Server version: 5.6.13-rel61.0 Percona and if I run the same first query on Server version: 5.5.5-10.0.4-MariaDB takes a very long time. All server configs are same. Server is running with 32 GB of RAM with AMD Opteron 8 cores with RAID 1 SSD. MySQL config files are all same on all instances as

```
port = 1979
socket = /opt/percona/tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
tmpdir = /tmp/
innodb_data_home_dir = /opt/percona/data
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /opt/percona/data
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 400
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 1024
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 1G
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 15G
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 0
interactive_timeout = 60
wait_timeout = 60
connect_timeout = 5
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 15
```

Can't seem to figure out what's going on. Tried to tune a few params but no luck. Is there a way we can improve the query or look at the server configs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dnc_contacts would benefit from 
INDEX(group_id, contact) and/or INDEX(contact, group_id)

Answer (score 4):

The two queries are not logically equivalent.

```
FROM contacts c LEFT JOIN `dnc_contacts` as B on c.`contact` <> B.`contact`
```

This does not do what you think it does.  This expression joins every row in c to every row in b except where contact is equal.  1000 rows in each table means ~999000 rows are being generated and compared.

```
FROM contacts c LEFT JOIN `dnc_contacts` as B on c.`contact` = B.`contact` and B.group_id = 3
WHERE b.contact is null AND c.phonebook_id = '62'
```

"Find all of the rows in C matched to the rows in B on matching contact  values and with B.group_id 3 if they exist, but WHERE you actually find a value for b.contact in a matching row, eliminate that row entirely from the results."

Comment: I'd also add indexes on `dnc_contacts (group_id, contact)` and on `contacts (phonebook_id, contact)`